# How to call procedure in mysql workbench

Tags: java, mysql, database

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE temp ( empId INT)
    BEGIN
     DECLARE var_etype VARCHAR(36);

SELECT 
    emptype = QOUTE(emptype)
FROM
    dms_document
WHERE
    id = empid;
SELECT 
    emptype,
    CASE
        WHEN emptype = 'P' THEN doctype
        ELSE 'No Documents required'
    END
FROM
    dms_report
WHERE
    pilot = 1;
End//
DELIMITER ;
```

I have created this procedure successfully but when I try to call it, I  am getting error 1305 the function  database.temp does not exist. I am trying to call using this statement:

```
SET @increment = '1';

select temp( @increment)
```

but I get Error, please tell me where I made mistake.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's documentation on [Using JDBC `CallableStatements` to Execute Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html) explains the necessary steps quite well.

This is what your java code needs to look like:

```
CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call temp(?)}");

cStmt.setInt(1, 42); //set your input parameter, empId, to 42.
```

If you want to work with the rows returned by your stored procedure's query in your Java code, you're also going to need to create an `OUT` parameter as noted in MySql's documentation page titled, [`CALL` Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html):

```
CALL can pass back values to its caller using parameters that are
declared as OUT or INOUT parameters
```

In order to call your stored procedure from MySQL workbench, use the `CALL` command. You can call stored procedure by directly setting values for each of the parameters:

```
SET @increment = 1;
CALL temp(@increment)
```

Then you simply use the `SELECT` statement to return the value of your output parameter

```
SELECT @outParameter
```

With help setting your output parameters, please read the article [MySQL Stored Procedure - SELECT - Example](http://www.sqlinfo.net/mysql/mysql_stored_procedure_SELECT.php).

Your stored procedure is syntactically wrong, and as mentioned in the comments, you're not using the stored procedure functionality for it's intended use. It's *intended* to be used for data manipulation not for querying. You should instead consider turning your procedure into a series of prepared statements.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: but i want to executed this in SqlWorkBEnch not in java code like call temp(1); but i am getting error while in routing i have that tempstoreprocdure

Comment: Updated the answer, you're still going to need an OUT parameter defined in your stored procedure. Please let me know if you have any questions! :O)

Comment: SET @increment = '1';
 call temp( @increment) like this am trying but still same issue am getting

Comment: It's because your stored procedure is syntactically wrong on a couple of occasions. you can't write: SELECT 
    emptype = QOUTE(emptype), as well as the statements that follow, you also need the output parameters. _all_ of your SP and it will work. Please let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: what out parameter we have to set

Comment: the value you want to display, hopefully it's singular. You are actually not using stored procedure for what it's meant for. It's not meant for querying like this, it's meant for data manipulation. You are better off using prepared statements actually.

Comment: http://snag.gy/kKGXN.jpg look this temp is in routine filed its store procdure look my query am trying call and am getting Erro

Comment: DECLARE increment INT;
SET increment = 1;
CALL temp(increment)
  Error coming  on DECLARE    http://snag.gy/lm93q.jpg

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment, view source code above please (it's changed). you can't perform a "SELECT temp(@incrment)" this isn't how mysql's query processing system and user-defined variables work.

Comment: SET @increment = 1;
CALL temp(@increment)  this Query i have used but still same Error is coming funcation not found

Comment: really  i am stucking why this Error coming

Comment: it's because your stored procedure don't work. Just because it shows up in the left side, DOES NOT mean it is functioning. Your stored procedure is incorrect on a couple of occasions. Please fix them and it will work with the above comments and code.

Comment: u have skype id or email id i wanna show my table structure if u free and comfort then

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call it, use use the keyword `call` and then procedure's name

```
 call procedureName(params);
```

in call of making an string

```
String sqlString = "procedureName("+?+")"; //in case of Integers


String sqlString = "procedureName('"+?+"')";//in case of Integers
bring the parameter in prepared statement.
```